# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: laravel, phpmailer

How to resolve this error? I do all possible things to resolve this issue but it cannot resolve. Here is my .env file code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=fluorine.cloudhosting.co.uk
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=contacts@cleansafeltd.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Hggjgjgghv123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Here is the code of mail.php.

```php
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'fluorine.cloudhosting.co.uk'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'contacts@cleansafeltd.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Contact'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Here is the mailController

```php
public function sendMail($to_email, $template_id, $users_insertId = 0) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSendmail();
    $mail->IsSMTP(true);
    $mail->Host = "fluorine.cloudhosting.co.uk";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Username = "website@cleansafeltd.com";
    $mail->Password = "Star9000!";
    $mail->Port = "465";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
}
```

I do all thin with tls or port 587 also but not solved.

Comment: Follow [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). You don't need to call `isSendmail()` as you're using SMTP. Other settings look OK, so it's likely your ISP blocks outbound SMTP. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` and see what the debug output says. The guide will help you figure out what's amiss.

Answer (score 0):

Using your credentials (by the way, you shouldn't post your password in public places, you better change it), I was able to send myself a mail using the following code

```php
Mail::to('mymail@domain')->send(new \App\Mail\TestMail);
```

`\App\Mail\TestMail` is a Mailable class, defined as follows

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    // Optional params are commented out. 
    // replyTo changes the address one gets when clicking the reply button
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'An alias name')
                    // ->to('mail@domain', 'alias name for recipient')
                    // ->cc('mail2@domain', 'alias name for cc')
                    // ->bcc('mail3@domain', 'alias name for bcc')
                    // ->replyTo('mail4@domain', 'alias for replyTo')
                    ->subject('This is a test')
                    ->view('mails.sample_mail'); // This is a laravel view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this one:

1. Setup your gmail account

   - Go to settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP

     ```
         - Check -> POP download: Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)

       - Check -> IMAP access: Enable IMAP

       - Save
     ```

     - Go to Google Account -> security -> Less secure app access

       - Set to **on** instead of off
2. Set this to your .env file

   MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

   MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com

   MAIL_PORT=465

   MAIL_USERNAME=your email username

   MAIL_PASSWORD=your email password

   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

   MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your email address

   MAIL_FROM_NAME=Your email name
3. Now you can send email with your smtp gmail account

Comment: Did he ask about how to send through gmail? No. Does your answer help him understand how to find out more about why it's not working? No.